# Answering consecutive inline queries makes no inline change

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, telegram, telegram-bot

Only the first initialResult is being rendered on my telegram client. The second response never even happens.
Is it even possible sending multiple consecutive results to a single call?

```
if (update.InlineQuery != null)
{
   if (update.InlineQuery.Query.Count() > 3)
   {
        var inlineQuery = update.InlineQuery;

        try
        {
            var initialResult = new InlineQueryResult[]
            {
                new InlineQueryResultArticle
                (
                    id: "1",
                    title: $"Loading...",
                    inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test") 
                ),
            };

            await Bot.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(inlineQuery.Id, initialResult, isPersonal: true, cacheTime: 0, nextOffset: null);

            var realResponse = new InlineQueryResult[]
            {
                new InlineQueryResultArticle
                (
                    id: "2",
                    title: $"this is real content",
                    inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test2") 
                ),
            };

            await Bot.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(inlineQuery.Id, realResponse, isPersonal: true, cacheTime: 0, nextOffset: null);
        } 

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try by setting  nextOffset: "offset_for_pagination" in the first call. because null value stops allowing you to retrieve and provide the subsequent set of results starting from that offset.

Comment: Can you try with the above two responses in a single call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible sending multiple consecutive results to a single call?

It is not possible to send two separate responses to a single inline query in Telegram using a single attempt. Each time you call the `AnswerInlineQueryAsync` method, it will provide a single response for that particular inline query.
The `InlineQueryResult[]` array will send it in one call to `AnswerInlineQueryAsync`. Each element in the array represents a single item that can be displayed to the user.

Using the code below is one approach to get consecutive responses.

```cs
if (update.InlineQuery != null)
{
    var inlineQuery = update.InlineQuery;

    try
    {
        var multipleResults = new InlineQueryResult[]
        {
            new InlineQueryResultArticle
            (
                id: "1",
                title: $"Loading...",
                inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test") 
            ),
            new InlineQueryResultArticle
            (
                id: "2",
                title: $"this is real content",
                inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test2") 
            ),
            // Add more InlineQueryResultArticle objects if needed...
        };

        await Bot.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(inlineQuery.Id, multipleResults, isPersonal: true, cacheTime: 0, nextOffset: null);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

By using below code is another approach to get consecutive responses.

```cs
if (update.InlineQuery != null)
{
    if (update.InlineQuery.Query.Count() > 3)
    {
        var inlineQuery = update.InlineQuery;

        try
        {
            var initialResult = new InlineQueryResult[]
            {
                new InlineQueryResultArticle
                (
                    id: "1",
                    title: $"Loading...",
                    inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test") 
                ),
            };

            await Bot.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(inlineQuery.Id, initialResult, isPersonal: true, cacheTime: 0, nextOffset: "offset_for_pagination");

            var realResponse = new InlineQueryResult[]
            {
                new InlineQueryResultArticle
                (
                    id: "2",
                    title: $"this is real content",
                    inputMessageContent: new InputTextMessageContent("test2") 
                ),
            };

            await Bot.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(inlineQuery.Id, realResponse, isPersonal: true, cacheTime: 0, nextOffset: null);
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions
        }
        finally
        {
            // Any cleanup or final operations
        }
    }
}
```

By passing `null` for `nextOffset`, you might prevent the second set of results from being displayed. To correct this issue:

- To set a valid `nextOffset` value for the first call to `AnswerInlineQueryAsync`.